# Resource interpreted as a font, but moved to the MIME-type

Tags: html, fonts, safari, safari-web-inspector

When we load a page in safari, in the console log we can see an error:

> Resource interpreted as a font, but moved to the MIME-type
>   application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template.

Font - `MagistralC-Bold.otf`

What is causing this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: check the server's response header in your browser's dev tools. What mime-type does the server say this file have? Because it should be saying something like `font/opentype`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how check headers ?

Comment: open your dev tools, go to the "network" tab, reload the page, and then find the transfer for your font file. Click it, and you should see all the network data like request and response headers, and communicated data.